# How can I imitate the Apple Watch activity complication to go past 100%?

Tags: swift, watchkit, watchos

I'm working on an Apple Watch app that tracks a type of daily progress. I want my complication to look like the Apple Activity complication where progress > 100% is shown with a full circle and a small break in the circle. But the complications and providers don't allow the `fillFraction` to be greater than 1. Is there a way to accomplish this?

Comment: Just set the ring style of the complication to closed.

Comment: @EmilioPelaez could you elaborate? I'm not seeing the desired effect. It still only reaches 100% fill and then stops. Setting a fillFraction of > 1 crashes the app.

Comment: Can't really elaborate since you haven't posted any code, but most, if not all, gauge complications have a ring style property. Did you look for it?

Comment: @EmilioPelaez Yeah i found the property, but it still doesn't allow the fill to be > 100%

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean now. That's not possible with regular complications. You might be able to do that with SwiftUI complications, but it'll require a custom control. Apple doesn't provide anything like that.